# Google directions API not following bends of streets

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem with the directions API. I want to get a route between two points, but if the path goes along a street that isn't absolutely straight, I'll get steps in the route that don't follow the street.

For example, in Buenos Aires I want the path from Avenida Juan B. Justo 1000 to Avenida Juan B.Justo 6000. According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/ I should call http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=juanbjusto1000buenosaires&destination=juanbjusto6000buenosaires&sensor=false

However, the response I get has only free points. Looking at the map, it's clear that this path doesn't follow the street as it should. When I look at the path, it goes straight through the middle of plenty of blocks. Am I calling the API wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoded polyline is what follows the streets:

```
"polyline" : {
    "points" : "tgarEvbscJ?@VXhAfBtC|DtDzFbCtDhCzDjCzDrC~DzAhCl@bAVZXPPDxCv@tB^zBd@nCl@v@Zt@d@zAjBnCjEpCtEbCxDnB`DfB`D`DpFvC|ErCxERZbCvDnC~ERZbCpDj@~@tB`DtAtB|@xA|BxDbC`EXd@dBvCHJ|DvGjB~Cd@v@j@z@`BvCdBtCZf@lChEtA|Bj@fAXd@pCrEPVFLNV^b@\\ZNN^Zl@h@t@p@|@x@xAnAXXFLP\\r@xAjCxF`AxB|@jBv@pBx@dB`BxDXl@Pb@^x@P`@RZ`@XXXVVxEjC\\RbBr@bA~Bz@nBHRzBxApE|DhA|@bCfCxBnERh@"
 }
```

[encoded polygon (so closed path)](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5b.html?encoded=tgarEvbscJ?@VXhAfBtC%7CDtDzFbCtDhCzDjCzDrC~DzAhCl@bAVZXPPDxCv@tB%5EzBd@nCl@v@Zt@d@zAjBnCjEpCtEbCxDnB%60DfB%60D%60DpFvC%7CErCxERZbCvDnC~ERZbCpDj@~@tB%60DtAtB%7C@xA%7CBxDbC%60EXd@dBvCHJ%7CDvGjB~Cd@v@j@z@%60BvCdBtCZf@lChEtA%7CBj@fAXd@pCrEPVFLNV%5Eb@%5CZNN%5EZl@h@t@p@%7C@x@xAnAXXFLP%5Cr@xAjCxF%60AxB%7C@jBv@pBx@dB%60BxDXl@Pb@%5Ex@P%60@RZ%60@XXXVVxEjC%5CRbBr@bA~Bz@nBHRzBxApE%7CDhA%7C@bCfCxBnERh@&parse=encoded)